# is there any hope for restoration of VisualStudio right-click-and-drag move and copy?

Tags: visual-studio-2010

Before VS2010, you could right-click-and-drag to move and copy, just in in Windows Explorer and Microsoft WORD.

The workdaround is ctrl-left-click-and-drag, which actually sometimes malfunctions, and you have to pretend to ctrl-left-click-and-drag to another window to get it working again:  behavior which I've seen at multiple companies, computers, and projects.

Comment: This is not a programming question.  Is off-topic for SO.

Comment: "Questions about general computing hardware and software are off-topic for Stack Overflow **unless they directly involve tools used primarily for programming**."

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Judging by [this feature request](http://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/522138/where-is-right-click-code-drag-option) at Microsoft, closed as "Won't fix", I reckon the feature was abandonned.